# MySQL error "Query execution was interrupted" after query_posts

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I use query_posts in long search query.
My query:

```
<?php $args = array(  
'tag_slug__in' => $cat_id,
'posts_per_page' => 15,
'paged' => $page,
'meta_query' => array(  
array(  
    'key' => 'Пол',  
    'value' => $value_sex,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Английский',  
    'value' => $english,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Французский',  
    'value' => $france,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Немецкий',  
    'value' => $germany,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Итальянский',  
    'value' => $italy,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Испанский',  
    'value' => $spain,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Китайский',  
    'value' => $chine,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Длина волос',  
    'value' => $hair_length,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Цвет волос',  
    'value' => $hair_color,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Удобные дни работы',  
    'value' => $value_days,
    'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Удобное время работы',  
    'value' => $value_time,
    'compare' => 'IN',
    'type' => 'CHAR',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Рост (см)',  
    'value' => array( $value_height, $value_height_max ),
    'type' => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Размер одежды',  
    'value' => array( $value_dress, $value_dress_max ),
    'type' => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
),
array(  
    'key' => 'Размер бюста',  
    'value' => array( $value_bust, $value_bust_max ),
    'type' => 'numeric',
    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
),          
 )  
 );
?>

<?php query_posts($args); ?>
```

This code is good work in new installed wordpress, but the old site is crashes.
I have "Query execution was interrupted", "Lost connection to MySQL server during query" and "MySQL server has gone away" errors in error.log
Key and value in meta_query in Russian. I'm sorry for my English. Please help.

[link to error.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gxc8eantlj34pvp/error_log.txt)

Comment: Query can be timeout if it's take more time in execution. I am not sure about Wordpress but maybe they have feature like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be a timeout problem, in which case you should tinker with your my.cnf, or maybe your mysql just becomes unresponsive due to excessive load, in which case raising the timeout limit won't help you.

There isn't much room to optimize wordpress default functions, but you could write your own query using $wpdb->query() method, and maybe give a look at current db indexes for the post's metadata.

Answer (score 1):

Put this line in after query_posts

```
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Comment: Yes, I have wp_reset_query(); after all query in site.

Comment: Dont know much about wordpress but this function youre using is NOT recommended even in the official documentation.http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts Are you using it in the main loop?